# Cygwin error that sysctl cannot be found in directory /usr/local/bin

Tags: cygwin, sysctl

Running `tuning-primer.sh` on Cygwin results in the error:
`sysctl not in directory /usr/local/bin` or `Error: Needed command "sysctl" not found in PATH!`

I have added *sysctl* code that I found on [this url](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/kernel/sysctl.c.html)

and created files `sysctl.c`, `sysctl.h` using *notepad++* and put it in the dir `/usr/local/bin` but still this error occurs.

Any solution ?...

[image: cygwin error screen]

Comment: And it's probably not needed. What's in the file?

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysctl

sysctl is not available on cygwin. Please note that there is no Kernel to tune.

If `tuning-primer.sh` (what ever is, you have not mentioned) expects to find `sysctl` than probably it is not supposed to be run on `Cygwin`